# How to fetch only one item into an array using implode function PHP

Tags: php

I created an array with only three items

```
$array = array('facebook', 'instagram', 'twitter');
```

Then I convert it into string using `implode()`

```
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
echo $comma_separated;
```

Now it's showing me the result into string format.

I want to fetch only first item `facebook` from that string.

now I want to make a conditional logic that

```
if($comma_separated == 'facebook'){
  echo 'facebook';
}
else{
 echo 'facebook don't exist anymore';
}
```

if i use `explode()` and i fetch value using `$comma_separated[0]`. it will fetch facebook for me. but what if i remove facebook from my array, then instagram will come at `0`

Comment: you went and completely change your question. That *"now I want to make a conditional logic that"* - should have been another question entirely. Both answers below answered the original question http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41355033/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array('facebook', 'instagram', 'twitter');

$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
echo $comma_separated;

// facebook,instagram,twitter

echo $array[0];
// facebook
```

or

```
$new = explode(',', $comma_separated);
echo $new[0];
// facebook
```

i don't understand your need.

why not use **in_array()** or **strpos()**

```
if (in_array('facebook', $array))
    echo 'facebook';
else
    echo 'not exist';
```

Comment: i used in_array()  and it solved my question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode again as :

```
    $array = array('facebook', 'instagram', 'twitter');
    $comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
    echo $comma_separated;
    // outputs :  facebook,instagram,twitter

    $first_item = explode(',',$comma_separated);
    if(in_array('facebook',$comma_separated)
    {
      echo "Found facebook";
    }
```